# Not sure how to use Junit to verify if an object is valid

Tags: java, object, junit, boolean, equals

I'm am trying to build a method in JUnit to test if an object is a Spherocylinder and I am unable to achieve coverage.

Here are the conditions I am trying to test.

-condition where equals method returns true

-condition for obj not being a spherocylinder

-condition for objects' label not being the same

-condition for objects' volumes not being equal

-condition for objects' cylinderheights not being equal

Here is the method and I trying to test.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

      if (!(obj instanceof Spherocylinder)) {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         Spherocylinder d = (Spherocylinder) obj;
         return (label.equalsIgnoreCase(d.getLabel())
               && Math.abs(radius - d.getRadius()) < 0.000001
               && Math.abs(cylinderHeight - d.getCylinderHeight())
                  < 0.000001);
      }  
}

   /**
    * hashcode method for equals method.
    * @return - return 0
    */
public int hashCode() {
      return 0;
}
```

And here is my test method I have written in Junit

```
 /**A test for equals() method. **/
   @Test public void equals() {
      Spherocylinder c1 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
      Spherocylinder c2 = new Spherocylinder("Different Example", 0.5, 0.25);
      Assert.assertFalse(c1.equals(c2));

      Spherocylinder d1 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
      Spherocylinder d2 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.6, 0.25);
      Assert.assertFalse(d1.equals(d2));

      Spherocylinder e1 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
      Spherocylinder e2 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.3);
      Assert.assertFalse(e1.equals(e2));

      Spherocylinder f1 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
      Spherocylinder f2 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
      Assert.assertEquals(f1, f2);
}
```

I believe I have all the conditions covered except for the following

-condition for obj not being a spherocylinder

How do I test this condition?

Comment: I think you could just compare a `Spherocyliner` with any old object, say a String.  (Remember the `equals()` method takes Object as a parameter, so you can pass it anything.)

Comment: `spherocylinder.equals(new Object())`

Comment: And: don't put all test into one method. Instead have one test method per condition. And then give the methods speaking names, such as testEqualsWithEqualSpheres for example. Rule of thumb: one assert per test method. And consider using assertThat and hamcrest matchers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
@Test public void testDifferentObjectTypes() {
    Spherocylinder c1 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
    String s = "I am not a Sheprocylinder";
    Assert.assertFalse(c1.equals(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, don't try to cover all scenarios in a single test method. That's not a good way to write test methods with intention of achieving code coverage.

Make many test methods for method to be tested for all scenarios and as per various outcome types i.e. positive and negative testing.

e.g.

```
@Test
public void testEquals_verifyObjectType_success(){
 // pass same type of objects 
}



@Test
    public void testEquals_verifyObjectType_failure(){
      // pass different type of objects like `String` and `Spherocylinder` 
    }

  @Test
    public void testEquals_verifylabelvalue_success(){
    }
@Test
    public void testEquals_verifylabelvalue_failure(){
    }
```

etc etc.

2. Make proper use of `@Before` method and not create too many object

   `@Before
   public static void setup{
    testObj1 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
    testObj2 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
    stringObject = new String("TEST_VALUE");
   }`

where `stringObject`  , `testObj1`  & `testObj2` are declared as fields in your class as `String` and `Spherocylinder` respectively.

3. In your test methods of step#1 , just before calling test method , try to tweak field values of these predefined objects by using setter and getter methods on objects as per the demand of scenario.

And make sure to restore these objects to original after test is executed and results verified. That is you reuse objects and take away base test data preparation part out of test method ( as far as possible ) .

With this set up in place , you can achieve desired coverage by simply adding a new method for left over scenario.

For this below,

> -condition for obj not being a spherocylinder

You simply need to call with a different object type ( like `stringObject` ) as already answered by Dave.